# How to have one RadioButtons group display in EditorTemplates in ASP.Net MVC(3)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, radio-button, mvc-editor-templates

I have a list of items from which I want the user to be able to input some value  select one
But the radio-buttons generated by the EditorTemplate are named like "Item[x].SelectedItemId" so they are totally independent from each other and I can't get the value...

Let's go show some code.
The model:

```
public class FormModel
{
    public List<ItemModel> Items { get; set; }
    public int SelectedItemId { get; set; }
}

public class ItemModel
{
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
    public string SomeString { get; set; }
}
```

The view:

```
@model FormModel
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{ 
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Items)
}
```

The editor template:

```
@model ItemModel
@Html.RadioButton("SelectedItemId", Model.ItemId)
@Model.ItemName <br/>
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SomeString) <br/>
```

**UPDATE**

This is what I want:

[image: What I want]

This is what I get:

[image: what I get]

As a result, FormModel.SelectedItemId never gets the value of any radio-button.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: MVC model binding is designed to handle collections properly right off the bat.  can you a sample of your POST controller action so we can see how you're trying to access the values?  Or is it the case that you need your rendered HTML to allow the end user to select the radio button for only one of the items on the list?

Comment: @ron.defreitas: that's the point, I need the user to be able to select the radio button for only one of the items in the list.

Answer (score 3):

It appears as though you are aware that setting the names for radio buttons to be the same is necessary to make them work. However, when you do that in an editor template by using the line of code `@Html.RadioButton("SelectedItemId", Model.ItemId)`, MVC 3 will take into consideration that you are in an editor template for Items and prepend items[n].

This would create a name of something like `name="Items[0].SelectedIndex"`. This would be fine if it weren't for the fact that the next radio button would be `name="Items[1].SelectedIndex".

One way to solve this is to not use an editor template and use a `foreach` loop instead. Here is some code that I was able to get functional. I confirmed that model-binding worked for the `SelectedIndex`.

```
    @model FormModel

    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    }

    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        foreach (var item in Model.Items)
        {
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.SelectedItemId, item.ItemId)
            @item.ItemName <br/>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => item.ItemName) <br/>
        }

        <input type="submit" value = "submit" />
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem, and we solved it with this piece of code.

```
@Html.RadioButton("", Model.Id, Model.Selected, new { Name = "deliveryMethod" })
```

You need to put Name property explicitly, so it will be used instead name that you get after `EditorFor` executes.

Comment: I would add that you will get a run-time error on this if you leave the first parameter "".  If you are looping through a list, you could put "deliveryMethod" + i, in for the first parameter.